# SSLError unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: docker, docker-compose, request, robotframework

I have a test script in `Robot Framework` which use `Request library` to send API request to external API services.

The test passed when run at local but failed when test run in docker.

I have set the `verify=False` when `create session`. The test is failed still.

Any idea, is that something wrong when I script API request at`Request Library` or `docker` I need to add something else at `docker-compose.yml`?

```
 SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='speech.srs', port=7070): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Browser
Library  String
Library  RequestsLibrary
Library  Collections
Library  RPA.JSON
Resource            ../Resources/BrowserFunctions.robot
Suite Setup         Start New Browser
#Test Setup          Test Setup
#Test Teardown       Test Teardown
Suite Teardown      Close Browser

*** Test Cases ***
001-Models-Deploy
    Log To Console    SRS must up. Otherwise, the test is supposed to fail......
  #Verify SRS model-deployer is up
    Create Session   mysession   ${SRS-API-model-deployer}    verify=False
    ${resp}=    GET    ${SRS-API-model-deployer}
    Status Should Be    OK    ${resp}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  robot-runner:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: /Dockerfile
    container_name: robot-runner
#    image: ppodgorsek/robot-framework:latest
    image: robot-runner:latest
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./BrowserTests:/opt/robotframework/tests
      - ./Resources:/opt/robotframework/Resources
      - ./test-audios:/opt/robotframework/test-audios
      - ./test-audios-additional-files:/opt/robotframework/test-audios-additional-files
      - ./test-audios-retrainAM:/opt/robotframework/test-audios-retrainAM
      - ./test-audios-retrainLM:/opt/robotframework/test-audios-retrainLM
      - ./test-audios-retrainLM:/opt/robotframework/test-audios-retrainLM-Auto-Text
      - ./test-Lexicon:/opt/robotframework/test-Lexicon
      - ./output-local:/opt/robotframework/reports
    environment:
      PYTHONWARNINGS: "ignore:Unverified HTTPS request"
    extra_hosts:
      - "speech.sts:172.17.0.1"
      - "speech.srs:172.17.0.1"
    networks:
      - sts_sts_network
networks:
  sts_sts_network:
    external: true
```

Comment: Did you try using `GET On Session` keyword instead of just `GET` ? Also, you could  add verify=False if you insist on using plain `GET`

Comment: I have tried verify=False at Create Session. Will try to use Get In Session see if it works.

Comment: updated here GET On Session works. i need to use session to control the request and response.